# wrapping kernel methods in ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to debug what may be a require/load problem in my environment (just printing `$"` & `$:` was not enough) I was hoping to wrap the load method, but my expected print statements do not execute, so I assume that the following did not work as I had hoped

```
module Kernel
  alias :old_load :load
  def load(fname, wrap=false)
    puts "loading #{fname}"
    old_load fname, wrap
  end
end
```

So is it generally possible to wrap kernel methods (using aliases or otherwise)?  If so whats would be the right syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me in 1.9.2.

Comment: Yep, works here too. just remember to `load` *after* this definition.

Comment: @tadman, @p4010 You guys are correct ... I was assuming that `require` will naturally invoke `load`, and thought to debug it there.  But it calls an internal C function `rb_load_internal` (see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/load.c), which would not be wrap-able in ruby.  I will accept either of yours as the right answer if you post it as such ... if you have any hints other than $: $", and strace that would be great too - Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if either of us provided the answer in this case. Why not self-answer with what you found out?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but wrapping `require` [seems to work](https://gist.github.com/1349281) for me.

Comment: @forforf - yes.  Just wrapping `require` works.  But what I wanted to capture were the `load`s that were a result of `require`.  But as I mentioned above, `require` calls a C function directly for the load, making it impossible to wrap (in ruby).

Comment: Ah, I see your issue now

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138634/can-i-over-ride-ruby-methods-written-in-c