# Inheritance of constructors in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, constructor

Lets say I create a new class which inherits from Symbol. Symbols are unique and it is very clear that the Symbol class has no Constructor. But which mechanism prevents the creation of a constructor in the child class? Is there some flag which makes all children unique?

```
class Syb < Symbol
   def initialize
   end
end
p Syb.respond_to? :new
false
```

Comment: `initialize` is not a constructor. It's an initializer. `new` is the constructor and it's missing. That's what would prevent you from creating instances of `Syb`

Comment: OK. And it's not possible to add a constructor later in the ancestry? That seems to make `sense`. But: `Symbol` is a child of `Object` and `Object` responds to `new`. That means to me `Symbol` deletes the constructor inherited from `Object`?

Comment: You actually can. And, off the top of my head, I can't tell how it'll affect the existing behavior of `Symbol`.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks a lot, now everything is clear for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio stated, my mistake was the mix up of constructor and initializer. Actually it is possible to write a new constructor for the Symbol class.

```
irb(main):001:1* class Symbol
irb(main):002:2*   def Symbol.new x
irb(main):003:2*     x.to_sym
irb(main):004:1*   end
irb(main):005:0> end
=> :new
irb(main):008:0> a = Symbol.new "xyz"
=> :xyz
irb(main):009:0> a
=> :xyz
```

Yes I realize that here the symbol is actually created by the `.to_sym` method. So `new` is not really a constructor but more like a wrapper for the real constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I also believe that is not a good idea to extend ruby core classes, [references](https://avdi.codes/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-rubys-core-classes-and-what-to-do-instead/)

In this case in particular

"For efficiency, many core class methods are coded in C instead of Ruby. And in some cases, such as this Array addition operator, they are implemented in such a way that the class of the return value is hardcoded."

If you take a look of the initialize method in the ruby Symbol class (it really has):

```
[36] pry(main)> require 'pry-doc'
=> true
[72] pry(main)> cd Symbol
[73] pry(Symbol):1> $ initialize

From: object.c (C Method):
Owner: BasicObject
Visibility: private
Signature: initialize()
Number of lines: 5

static VALUE
rb_obj_dummy0(VALUE _)
{
    return rb_obj_dummy();
}
```

So we can see that this method allready exists and it is implemented in c, but there is a limitation about overiding ruby core classes methods, explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138888/1900722)

And I also believe that is really important to investigate ruby with, pry pry-doc and pry-gem

Comment: Yes, that might be true. But this wasn't the question. In my example the class Syb isn't trying to use its parent constructor.

Comment: I thins taht the real answer that you were looking is the one that I point now, in te answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138888/1900722

Answer (score -1):

> Lets say I create a new class which inherits from Symbol. Symbols are unique and it is very clear that the Symbol class has no Constructor.

This statement is trivially true, since Ruby has no constructors.

> But which mechanism prevents the creation of a constructor in the child class?

The fact that Ruby has no constructors prevents the creation of a constructor.

> Is there some flag which makes all children unique?

No.